# How to find where the program is waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a big code base. It is heavily multithreaded.

After running the `linux based` application for a few hours, in the end, right before reporting, the application silences. It doesn't die, it doesn't crash, it just waits there. Joins, mutexes, condition variables ... any of these can be the culprit.

If it had crashed, I would at least have a chance to find the source using debugger. But this way, I have no clue *how* to use *what* tool to find the bug. I can't even post a code sample for you. The only thing that can possibly help is to tap MANY places with `cout` to get a visual where the application is.

Have you been in such a situation? What do you recommend?

Comment: Visual Studio has parallel stacks window.

Comment: Which platform is this? Some debuggers can be attached to a running process; GDB certainly can.

Comment: More information on your environment would be helpful - there's no point suggesting a tool that will help if it's not supported on your system. Also note that in a multi-threaded application, it's common for many threads to be in a wait state. Check the thread stacks and see if any are permanently waiting for a mutex... that may hint at the issue.

Comment: You have given the answer yourself: Spamming `cout` in combination with debugging will certainly help. But I admit that it seems you are facing a tough challenge.

Comment: I also suggest getting it to run for only a few seconds and then reach the end.

Comment: ***Have you been in such a situation?*** Yes in the late 1990s I wrote a 250 thousand line telemammography application that had around 45 threads in a thread pool. ***What do you recommend?*** Good logging and also get very familiar with your debugger.

Comment: Sorry, for not supplying more info. As  TobiMcNamobi pointed out, I was devastated :( . The platform is linux

Comment: And based on http://stackoverflow.com/users/573982/artak-begnazaryan answer, I realized that in this special case, I had to provide measures for network failure (upon querying database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running under Linux then just use `gdb` to run the program. When the application 'silences', interrupt it with `CTRL+C`, then type `backtrace` to see the call stack. With this you will find out the function where your application was blocked.

Comment: fantastic, will it matter if this is a multi threaded application or not?

Comment: to see all backtraces in a multi threaded application, just type `thread apply all backtrace`

Answer (score 1):

Incase of linux, **gdb** will be great help.  Another tool that can be of great help is **strace** (This can also be used where there are problems with program for with source is not readily available because strace does not need recompilation to trace them.)

strace shall intercept/record system calls that are called by a process and also the signals that are received by a process. It will be able to show the order of events and all the return/resumption paths of calls. This can take you almost closer to the area of problem.

**iotop**, **LTTng** and **Ftrace** are few of other tools that be helpful to you in this scenario.